# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `responsive` of type `string` supplied to `Image`, expected `boolean`

Tags: html, reactjs, reactive-programming

Line in question:

```
<Poster 
  info="info" 
  id={movie.id} 
  path={movie.poster_path} 
  title={movie.title} 
  popularity={movie.popularity} 
  genres={genres} 
  responsive="responsive"
/>
```

Should be really simple i just cant work out how to change responsive="responsive" into the right boolean what is it expecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The component Poster expects `responsive` prop to be a boolean and not a string. A boolean true value can simply be passed like

```
<Poster 
    info="info"
    id={movie.id}
    path={movie.poster_path}
    title={movie.title} popularity={movie.popularity}
    genres={genres}
    responsive
/>
```

or

```
    <Poster 
    info="info"
    id={movie.id}
    path={movie.poster_path}
    title={movie.title} popularity={movie.popularity}
    genres={genres}
    responsive={true}
/>
```

and a false value can be given like

```
<Poster 
    info="info"
    id={movie.id}
    path={movie.poster_path}
    title={movie.title} popularity={movie.popularity}
    genres={genres}
    responsive={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get the below error because the responsive property expects `boolean` but you are actually passing a `string value` to it. You might have defined prop-type for `responsive` in Poster component like below so it expects only boolean value

```
Poster.propTypes = {
  responsive: PropTypes.bool
}
```

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `responsive` of type `string` supplied
>   to `Image`, expected `boolean`

So to fix the warning, you need to pass boolean value (true or false) to responsive prop

```
<Poster info="info" id={movie.id} path={movie.poster_path} title={movie.title} popularity={movie.popularity} genres={genres} responsive={false}/>
```

OR

```
 <Poster info="info" id={movie.id} path={movie.poster_path} title={movie.title} popularity={movie.popularity} genres={genres} responsive={true}/>
```

If you want to pass only string value to responsive prop then you need to set the prop type string to it in your Poster component like below

```
Poster.propTypes = {
  responsive: PropTypes.string
}
```